# Is there a way to make a TreeView appear always fully expanded?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView on my form but I'd like it to always be fully expanded, even the child nodes.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Do you want it to initially display expanded? If so, then call the [`ExpandAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.expandall(v=VS.100).aspx) method on the root node after you have added all of the tree nodes.

If you want it to display expanded and not allow the user to collapse it, then you need to handle the [`BeforeCollapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecollapse.aspx) event and cancel it. (Set `e.Cancel = true;`).

Comment: Actually it does not have to be after adding **all** the tree nodes, but at least one. This is useful information if you have a tree that will always be updated.

Comment: @kdmin: I think you would always want to call `ExpandAll()` after all of the tree nodes have been added so that the expansion happens after the control initialization occurs; otherwise I think the state of the nodes can get out of sync.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use [`TreeView.ExpandAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.expandall) like this:

```cs
private void myCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // If the check box is checked, expand all the tree nodes.
   if (myCheckBox.Checked == true)
   {
      myTreeView.ExpandAll();
   }
   else
   {
      myTreeView.CollapseAll();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**In WPF**, one way is to keep your tree view fully expanded:

```xml
<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @IgnacioAra, Its updated now to text.

Answer (score 3):

Guessing here...  On the BeforeCollapsed event, set e.Cancel = true;

Comment: Probably a combination of what I said plus what Ashton said.  Is this for a WinForm or a WebForm?  I think they both have a TreeView control.

Answer (score 1):

[TreeView.ExpandAll Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.expandall.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the TreeNode.EnsureVisible Method - [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.ensurevisible(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
private void ManagerFolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    treeView.ExpandAll();
    treeView.Nodes[0].FirstNode.Collapse();
    treeView.Nodes[4].FirstNode.Collapse();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be wondering where to put the `treeview1.expandAll()` statement? You cannot put it in the Designer's generated code, or it will be deleted at the next form refresh/save.

I've put it in the "Form1.cs" code, in the partial class part which deals with the form initialization, and it works. Just after the InitializeComponent() statement (if you don't know what I'm talking about, just find that statement)

Hope it helps :)

PD. Thanks for your support, you're great, guys!